# Why we need StreamingFileSink when there is exists BucketingSink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I found [BucketingSink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/BucketingSink.html) can do everything the [StreamingFileSink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/filesystem/StreamingFileSink.html) can do, such as write events to local files, NAS or HDFS files(Original I thought the BucketingSink just can write events to HDFS and cannot write to NAS or local files), however some functions StreamingFileSink doesn't provides which BucketingSink provides , such as the StreamingFileSink cannot set the Prefix and Suffix of the file, however BucketingSink can do, so Why we need StreamingFileSink when there is exists BucketingSink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamingFileSink` is a new sink that will eventually replace `BucketingSink`. `BucketingSink` has some major limitation (consistent output to S3, support for blocking formats such as Parquet and ORC) that cannot be resolved without a redesign. `StreamingFileSink` implements this new design.

However, as you've noticed in the current state (Flink 1.6), `StreamingFileSink` does not support all features of `BucketingSink` yet.